# Call service from outside of ROS

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I have a programm, that is supposed to work in a ROS environment.
This programm has been written in a multi-platform framework and will most likely be run on a mobile OS, but should be OS-independent after all.

It should be able to send messages to a ROS service and receive messages from that service.
I wanted to ask how that could be achieved since there is no ROS environment set up on the app itself.

I would need some kind of wrapper that sends stuff that looks like propper messages on ROS. I couln't find anything but maybe there is already a framework or you could point me to do it and where I should start.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212753/call-service-from-outside-of-ros/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found what I was searching for with rosbridge. It allows to send out json messages via UDP proxy to access ROS functionality: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite

---

Originally posted by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) with karma: 111 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1